# pySpark indexing dataframe: No space left on the device

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

The source table has many columns namely

[image]

The table is partitioned on year,year_month and tran_datetime

table size : 590000000

each partition has roughly 50000000 rows

the data is being written to S3.

I am trying add index to the above table with below code , but i am getting the bellow error. I am not sure what is causing it.

```
Spark 2.3
Total Memory:1.2TB and cores: 35

Driver.cores  5
Driver.memory  37G
executor.cores  5
executor.memory  37G
driver.memoryOverhead  5120
executor.memoryOverhead  5120
```

Code is in the image below.

[image]

Can some one please explain me this error, why is this coming and what dose it mean by no space left.

Comment: The error says that your worker/driver machine ran out of **disk** space. Have you checked that?

Comment: but given the amount of resources that should not happen right? and df -h is showing i have space.

Comment: We wouldn't know. The question contains neither the code nor the config. But you seem to be assuming that having a lot of memory would prevent Spark from using the disk. That isn't accurate.

Comment: code is in the image.. i just mentioned it as well

Comment: What is `"path"` that you're writing parquet files to?

Comment: just a path in s3.

Comment: I think that's going to be a process of elimination. My first suspicion is that workers are running out of disk space and spilling partitions to disk (for whatever task) is failing. This is probably obvious, but worth asking whether you've checked that your 0.6Bn records will fit in your available memory (which in all other respects is prodigious). Do you have maybe have a view of the UI?

Comment: yes i do, can you tell me what i should check ? i am fairly new to this so.

Comment: wait... why does your window have no partition? the partitioned data is sent through a single partition (worker) which might be the reason it runs out of memory